# Correct term for an instance when it's in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminology

*objects table*

```
  id | tf      |
   0 | false   |
```

*ruby code*

```
Object.find(0).tf = true  
Object.find(0).update_attributes(tf: true)
```

The first method chain updates an **instance** of object 0. The second updates ... what exactly? A object 0's row? I'm writing notes for myself on RoR, and I keep stumbling when it comes to referring to an instance stored in the database!

Comment: Not really an answer, but during development (unless you've messed a lot with development.rb) you should see debug statements that show all the SQL that gets submitted to the database.  Keep an eye on that and it should be enlightening in terms of what actually happens in each case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll see people use instance, object, and row as words to refer to a persisted object. Your best bet for making this distinction is to use a qualifier like "persisted" or "in the database" whenever your meaning might be ambiguous. In Rails, using "record" would be most accurate, in keeping with the convention of the ActiveRecord library.

Answer (score 2):

This is largely a matter of personal preference, I believe. I personally use 'row' or 'record' for 'that thing in the database', and 'object' or 'instance' for 'that thing in application memory'.

Answer (score 0):

They both update an instance. Find executes a query that loads the information from the database into an instance of that object. The `tf=` method (assuming this is normal functionality) changes the `tf` value of that instance, but does not save it. The `update_attributes` method is quite literally (from the source):

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb, line 2665
def update_attributes(attributes)
  self.attributes = attributes
  save
end
```

This sets the attributes, and then calls `save`, simply saving you a step.

Comment: I'm talking about the end result of each method.